# Nuxt generate dynamic routes constantly

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, dynamic-routing

I use this code below to create static files for my dynamic routes!

```js
generate: {
  routes: function () {
    return axios.get(
    'https://www.myapi.com/admin/wp-json/wp/v2/teams'
    )
    .then((response) => {
      let teams = response.data.map((team) => {
          return {
            route: '/teams/' + team.id,
            payload: team
          }
      });
      return [...teams]
    });
  }
}
```

Suppose we have 10 teams when generate nuxt, and nuxt create 10 static html for each of them. But teams count is not constant. e.g. one hour later we have 15 teams. So, How this handle by nuxt ? Is there any way to run npm run generate constantly to make new routes for new teams without do it locally manual and upload to server ?

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Comment: No my friend i upload my dist folder in my plesk httpdocs but i dont know how to work to achive such a funcionality! I continue to run localy npm run generate and i upload dist folder via ftp!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, you usually rely on webhooks. A common usage is if your Nuxt app is hosted on Netlify and you're using any kind of headless CMS.

Here is an article [on Prismic](https://medium.com/js-dojo/deploying-nuxt-js-prismic-with-netlify-a53c551d6e0f) and how to handle that in this case.

Overall, if you want to rebuild your Nuxt app in SSG mode, you need to notify the platform it's hosted on, to make a `npm run generate` when your team number changes.
A webhook is common practice regardless of the platform.